# changing the start point in svg circle

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I want to use the below SVG but the the fill starts from 3 O clock.
I want the fill to start from 12 O clock.
Please give suggestions on how to achieve that.

```
    <svg id="svg" width="200" height="200" viewPort="0 0 100 100" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48"
  stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
   <text id="percentile" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" stroke="#191919"
   stroke-width="1px" font-size="35" dy="0.3em">{{pct}}</text>
   <!--<text id="percentile" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" stroke="#191919"
   stroke-width="1px" font-size="20" dy="-0.3em">Percentile</text>-->
  <circle id="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent"
  stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
</svg>
```

[image: SVG circle]

Comment: apply a rotate transform to the circle.

Comment: @Robert Rotating the circle will rotate the text also... so I don't want to rotate the SVG circle

Comment: I tried to rotate the circle, text inside the circle is also rotated with it

Comment: The you're doing it wrong. Apply the rotate transform to the circle as I said in my first comment. Ask a new question showing your attempt if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you are using the image to show some kind of progress, i.e. it starts at completely gray, then gradually fills up with yellow starting from 3 o'clock as the proportion goes from 0 to 1 (or 0% to 100%), and the image shows what it looks like at 50%. You want to shift the start from 3 o'clock to 12 o'clock.

**Update:** The original solution I posted here suggested that you could solve this problem by using `stroke-dashoffset`. However, that solution was incorrect: it only works for small percentages of the circle, and breaks down once you try to fill larger proportions of the circle. The updated solution below shows an implementation of the suggestion in the comments below the original question. It involves rotating the circle. The demo code below also addresses one of the concerns you expressed for this solution in your comments, i.e. the demo code shows that if the rotation is applied only to the circle, it should not affect text that is placed within the circle.

```html
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="200">
  <g transform="">
    <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="20"></circle>
    <circle id="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="70.69 494.80" transform="rotate(0, 100, 100)"></circle>
    <text x="35" y="100" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">Text inside circle</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(250)">
    <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="20"></circle>
    <circle id="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="70.69 494.80" transform="rotate(-90, 100, 100)"></circle>
    <text x="35" y="100" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">Text inside circle</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @andrew... it helped me a lot to understand... Please share me some tutorials on this, so I can learn little more about formulae and other things we can do on it...  :)

Comment: I found the following tutorials through a quick simple Google search for either "svg tutorial" or "svg dasharray dashoffset tutorial". I'm sure there are many more good ones out there. One tutorial called ["How to create a radial progress bar with SVG"](http://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2015-03-19-radial-svg-progressbar.html) deals with almost exactly the same problem your question addresses. MDN, the Mozilla Developer Network, is always a good source of information, and they have [a basic SVG tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial) that I'm sure is good.

Comment: Two other tutorials on animating line drawing (which is what you're trying to do with your circle) are [here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) and [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/) but, again, there are probably many more good ones like them out there.

Comment: Make sure you test on iOS devices as well as desktop. Some start rendering circles at 0300 as per the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#CircleElement , but some (ios) devices start at 1200. Solution: use two semicircular arcs in a path instead of a circle.